# how to lazy load only once in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lazy-loading

I am lazy loading service file dynamically on demand from a method, which gets called multiple times and i have to wait until i get response even though i had loaded that file before. Can i load it only once?

```
processData(serviceName: any, methodName: any) {        
        import(`./${serviceName}Service`)
        .then(component =>{
            var result = component.default[methodName] ? component.default[methodName]() : [];        
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(`Model not yet supported` + error);
        return null;
      });
    }
}
```

I have written above method to dynamically lazy load service file, it works fine. But processData() gets called many times(onchange of any control) and most of the times the files would have already imported once.
I do not want to load that file again. How or where can i implement this? I will not get serviceName parameter until home page route is called.
where can i lazy load import and use it forever in application?

Comment: Why does processData get "called many times"? Where is it being called from? Might `useEffect` or `useCallback/useMemo` hooks help here?

Comment: Could you post the full code example where this is getting called?

Comment: processData method gets called onchange of some controls. i am using class component. Cannot use useEffect

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a name-spaced object.

```
const servicesCache = {};

processData(serviceName: any, methodName: any) {

    if (servicesCache[serviceName]) {
        var result = servicesCache[methodName];
    } else {
        import (`./${serviceName}Service`)
        .then(component => {
                servicesCache[serviceName] = component.default[methodName] ? component.default[methodName]() : [];
                var result = servicesCache[serviceName];
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(`Model not yet supported` + error);
                return null;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: i am doing this import in 2-3 places? is there anyway i can do it one place?